# error of -gt operator not found in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I am trying to write a shell script that takes an unspecified no. of command line arguments upto 9 and finds their sum. The number should be added to sum only if it is greater than 10.
The code that I have tried is

```
#!/bin/sh
sum=0
for i in $@
do
        if [$i -gt 10]
        then
                sum=$((sum+i))
        else
                continue
        fi
done
echo $sum
```

But I am getting the following error when I try to execute

```
xyz@LAPTOP-1NOBF8F8:~$ vi Sum2.sh
xyz@LAPTOP-1NOBF8F8:~$ chmod +x Sum2.sh
xyz@LAPTOP-1NOBF8F8:~$ ./Sum2.sh 19 5 3
./Sum2.sh: 5: [19: not found
./Sum2.sh: 5: [5: not found
./Sum2.sh: 5: [3: not found
0
```

Please let me know what am I missing .

Comment: Save yourself some trouble by running your scripts through [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net)

Comment: @dishaNasa : You are missing a space. As the error message tells, you, when `i` has the value i.e. 19, `[$i` expands to a command `[19`, and this command does not exist in your PATH.

Answer (score 1):

`[` is a *command* so should be separated from surrounding stuff by whitespace<sup>(a)</sup>, as should the `]` terminator:

```sh
if [ $i -gt 10 ]
```

See the following transcript for an example:

```sh
pax> [4 -gt 3] && echo yes
[4: command not found

pax> [ 4 -gt 3 ] && echo yes
yes
```

---

<sup>(a)</sup> It's no different to expecting `ls-al` to work without the space between the `s` and `-`.

Answer (score 0):

`[` needs to be followed by space (and `]` needs to be preceeded by one as well).